# PHP remove all characters before certain string

Tags: php, regex, string

I need to grep certain string(with bold) from any string with regular expression.

Sample data:

"drog stabilizatorja Meyle RE **16-16 060 0004/HD**"

"koncnik Meyle RE **16-16 020 0013**"

"gumica stabilizatorja Meyle RE **16-14 079 9404/S**"

I think it would be ok if I cut all characters before first number in string.
I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regex:

```
$str = "drog stabilizatorja Meyle RE 16-16 060 0004/HD";
preg_match("/[^\\d*](\\d.*)/", $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Output:

> 16-16 060 0004/HD

Comment: Thank you. What if I have other characters in string like /.
Sample string:
"drog stabilizatorja Meyle AU/SE/SK/VW 116 060 0000/HD"

Comment: `drog stabilizatorja Meyle AU/SE/SK/VW 116 060 0000/HD` gets trimmed to `116 060 0000/HD`. Isn't this what you want to get?

Comment: Sorry, it is ok, I had to refresh :)

Comment: Please accept this answer (tick the checkbox), so someone who visits this page later can directly see what he should try.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex :

```
'\d+-\d+.*'
```

Answer (score 0):

Kasra's solution is the most simple one and works perfectly. However, if you want to ensure the specific pattern that your samples seem to have, this would be a "specialized" method:

```
$samples = array(
    "drog stabilizatorja Meyle RE 16-16 060 0004/HD",
    "koncnik Meyle RE 16-16 020 0013",
    "gumica stabilizatorja Meyle RE 16-14 079 9404/S"
);

$result = array();

foreach ($samples as $sample) {
    if (preg_match('@(\d{2}\-\d{2}\s\d{3}\s\d{4}(/\w+)?)@', $sample, $matches)) {
        $result[] = $matches[0];
    }
}

print_r($result);

// Output:
//
// Array
// (
//     [0] => 16-16 060 0004/HD
//     [1] => 16-16 020 0013
//     [2] => 16-14 079 9404/S
// )

(\d{2}\-\d{2}\s\d{3}\s\d{4}(\/\w+)?)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Exr20FNZItIuK0My)

Answer (score 0):

> I think it would be ok if I cut all characters before first number in string. I am not sure how to do it.

You can use `^.*?(?=\d)` as far as your above statement is concerned. And replace with `''` (empty string).

[Demo and explanation](https://regex101.com/r/cO1rT6/1)

**Note:** If you want to extract out digits Kasra's solution is the best and if you want to match and replace you can use this.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the string...

```
$str = "drog stabilizatorja Meyle RE 16-16 060 0004/HD";
$str = preg_replace( '/.*([^\\d*](\\d.*))/', '\1', $str);
echo $str;
```